# Need some help understanding how the asp:UpdatePanel works

Tags: asp.net

I'm encountering this issue which I cannot really understand what is exactly happening. 
So I have my Default.aspx page where I register 2 UserControls, i.e. logctrl and valctrl . From the logctrl I want to update a textarea within the valctrl when i press a particular button. Everything works fine until I introduce a asp:UpdatePanel to show a loading modal. 
For some reason the textarea is not populated after I click on the same button in the logctrl.

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="380px" CssClass="background1">    
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <uc2:logctrl id="CtrlLog" runat="server"></uc2:logCtrl>
            <uc1:valctrl id="CtrlVal" runat="server"></uc1:valCtrl>
        </div>        
</asp:Panel>
```

logctrl.ascx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="logonButton" runat="server" Text="Logon" OnClick="logonButton_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress id="updateProgress" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/loading.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." style="padding: 10px;position:fixed;top:45%;left:50%;" />
            </div>
            <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                <span style="border-width: 0px; position: fixed; padding: 50px; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 36px; left: 40%; top: 40%;">Loading ...</span>
            </div>            
        </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add triggers to the update panel to let it know that something has changed. you have to tell is which control and which event of that control is triggering the update.Alternatively you can set the update mode property of update panel to "always".in the designer view click on properties of the update panel to add triggers